# How to deploy my Angular 13 app ( created in visual studio code) and Net Core Api (created in visual studio 2022) in IIS

Tags: angular, rest, .net-core, iis

How to deploy my Angular 13 app ( created in visual studio code) and Net Core Api (created in visual studio 2022) in IIS
Or
Is there any other way to publish like self deploy?

I have create app in visual studio code and api in net core (dotnet --version 7.0.102). Now I want to deploy it in dev and production environment.

Comment: You can refer to: Host the Angular with .Net core application in IIS: https://support.boldbi.com/kb/article/335/how-to-host-the-angular-with-net-core-application-in-iis. Deploy Angular app to IIS: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-angular-app-to-an-iis-web-server-complete-setup-337997486423. Publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio.

Comment: Thanks @TengFeiXie. But I am able to host my both app.

Comment: **PreRequisite**
AspNetCoreModuleV2 - Download for Microsoft downloan section
UrlRewrite -  search google - (optional)
**IIS Deploy of API**
1. Add a Website 
 -Alias - ABCAPI 
 -App Pool-ABCAPI
 - Phyical Path-(Published Content Folder - Path)
 - Connect As (Credential of Admin User)
 - Port No : XX (Any)
**IIS Deploy of ABCCLI**
1. Go To Default Website
 - Add Application
 - Name ABCCLI - (Name must be same as you mentioned at the time of publishing)
 - Application Pool - DefualtAppPool
 - Phyical Path-(Published Content Folder - Path)
 - Connect As (Credential of Admin User)